# Unable to display list view using adapter in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

LogCat is as follows :

```
08-10 13:41:58.533  19439-19445/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-10 13:42:01.609  19439-19439/com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp/com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4637)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:41)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove the Fragment My Code works else it doesn't work. Even the Debugger couldn't find out anything for me. I tried using class instead of android:name which too didn't workout for me

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        class="com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

NewsFragment.java

```
package com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView mListView;
    private List<String> newsList;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        mListView =(ListView)fragementView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        newsList  = new ArrayList<String>();
        newsList.add("My First Item on the list");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");
        newsList.add("More");


        mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

        return fragementView;
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return newsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return newsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View rowView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);

            return rowView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_news.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your fragment "Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment"

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira yeah it is an unique android id as you can see in the code

Comment: No. I don't see any unique Id in your fragment xml

Comment: @PedroOliveira myListView is the unique id for ListView right ?

Comment: I'l talking about the fragment not the listview... You should read your logcat information

Comment: @PedroOliveira So sorry it just worked

Comment: @PedroOliveira Thank You ! I thought there was some problem with inflating the view in a fragment and I couldn't find it while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Pedro Oliveira I thought there is some problem with inflating the view in a fragment. So sorry :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/unquieId"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        class="com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's right. That's the magic line `android:id="@+id/unquieId"`. Glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

Your activity class derive from `AppCompatActivity`. Your fragment derives from standard `fragment`. For fragments, you have to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Just for example, check [here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)